# Getting back to the original coordinates from a warped Image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have four corners extracted from a image,

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> ecken;
ecken.push_back(corners[0]);
ecken.push_back(corners[size.height-1]);
ecken.push_back(corners[size.area()-size.height-1]);
ecken.push_back(corners[size.area()-1]);
```

they are warped in to a second image:

```
quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, quad.rows));

        // Get transformation matrix
            cv::Mat transmtx = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(ecken, quad_pts);
cv::warpPerspective(src, quad, transmtx, quad.size(),1);
```

I want to go back to the original image from  the result that I get in quad, these what I've tried:

```
cv::Mat trans  = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(quad_pts,ecken );
        cv::perspectiveTransform(quad,test,trans); /// I'm not sure that this correct and the program crashes here
```

and here the error message in the console:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn + 1 == m.cols && (depth == CV_32F || depth =
= CV_64F)) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp
, line 1926
```

and it didn't work !! 
any idea ??

Comment: Copy pasted from the Meta FAQ: If "something goes wrong" tell us what. If it's an exception, post the full stack trace. If it's a compile-time error, post the exact error message. (Not "something like this" but cut and paste.)

Comment: I'm not a specialist of opencv but this looks like there is a mismatch of format (dimension or depth) between image and transform.

Comment: What are `quad` and `test`?

Comment: they are both cv::Mat type

Answer (score 0):

Your two Mat objects are of different depth. Check by printing Mat.depth() that both have the same image type. It could be that one of them is grayscale and the other colour.

Comment: No they have the same type